# Which of the two sentences is grammatically correct? Do they mean the same?

Tags: sentence-choice

> "What brand is your guitar?"
>
> "What brand guitar do you play?"

I suppose the first one is grammatically correct, is the second one correct as well?

They mean the same thing, right?

Comment: "brand of guitar" / "guitar brand"

Comment: @lekon You are correct. They mean the same thing, although the second question is more clear and complete. Both are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What brand of guitar

What brand guitar

What guitar brand

> What brand of guitar do you recommend?
>
> What guitar brand do you recommend?
>
> What brand guitar do you play?

You cannot play a "brand".  You play a guitar of a particular make or brand.

Answer (score 0):

Both are gramatically correct.

Both mean 99% the same thing, except in rare cases - if you ask someone who owns a guitar but never plays it, or if you ask someone who owns a guitar and perhaps plays it more or less often, but right now is playing someone else's guitar.

Answer (score 0):

To me both seem grammatically correct. Though 2nd one is more clear to ask.

Comment: Could you also explain why you think what you think? Answers aren't useful without explanations.

Comment: You are absolutely right but my grammar isn't too good so I am not able to explain it (Sorry for that). But still both of your sentences seem correct.